# finding elements with z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was working on an issue in which I was looping through same controls placed on a single page and assigning a z-index to them.

I want to get a collection of all the elements which currently have the z index defined either directly in html or using css, and then iterate over them top to bottom and assign their z-index using JQuery.

What would the selector for this look like, and how performant would it be?

Comment: Why down vote for?That is perfectly valid question.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar It wasn't me, but I assume its' because the OP has shown no attempt to achieve this himself.

Comment: It would be *very bad* performancewise, yes. Please tell us about your issue instead of asking about how to get z-indices. ([XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: I did try it myself solving the issue that I was working on with this code $(document).ready(function() {
    
    var val = 100;
    $('.wrapper .selectbox').each(function (i, obj) {     
        
        $(obj).css('z-index', val);
        val = val-10;

    });

}); It was just a though that came in my mind thinking if we can set the z index for all items on the page someway.Not sure how this could be done so that's why asked the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific selector to achieve this, so you would need to use `filter()` like this:

```
var zIndex = 5;
var $zElements = $('.selector').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('z-index') == zIndex;
});

$zElements.each(function() {
    // loop through the elements with a matching z-index
});
```

Comment: I've never tried this before, but Chrome reports "auto" as the z-index when no value is set. Is this what all browsers do?

Comment: @Blazemonger yeah, that's right. Certain CSS properties (such as `width`, `height`) have `auto` as their default value.

Comment: Ah good, so if OP wants to get ALL elements with SOME z-index set (which is how I read the question) he just needs to loop through them and filter out every element with `auto` as a value. Easy-peasy.

Comment: Ah, yes indeed. I read it that he was looking for elements with a specific `z-index` value. If that's not the case it's a simple amendment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I get the idea now.